# Calculating number of days between an existing date on a table and current date

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate the number of days between a range of dates stored on the same table. No problem doing so using the DATEDIFF query where I have both start and end dates present in the table. I am struggling to calculate the days where I only have a start date (table is service history of employees who work part-time and the the most recent line of data is open ended) and would therefore like to use the current date to replace the blanks in order to calculate service to date.

[Further information attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtnOg.jpg)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results is helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce()` and the current date.  In ANSI SQL, this would be `coalesce(end_date, CURRENT_DATE)`.

However, `datediff()` suggests SQL Server (or perhaps MySQL).  In SQL Server:

```
select datediff(day, start_date, coalesce(end_date, getdate())) as days_of_service
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '1/1/2018', '4/4/2018');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Oracle, if you are interested (or anyone else):

```
select trunc(sysdate - to_date('03/04/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')) as days,
       trunc(mod(sysdate - to_date('03/04/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),1) * 24) as hours,
       trunc(mod(mod(sysdate - to_date('03/04/2018','dd/mm/yyyy'),1) * 24, 1) * 60) as minutes
  from dual
```

Querying `sysdate - to_date('some date','dd/mmy/yyyy')` will return you the number of days, minutes, seconds, etc as a floating point number. In order to get the correct amount of hours and minutes, you would need to get only the *decimal* part of it (by means of the `mod` operator) and then multiplying it by 24, and 60, respectively.